# Table of content in suftesi document class shows only names of articles, but not section titles

Tags: table-of-contents, suftesi

I use `suftesi` for a book with several articles. The table of content for the book shows only the title of the articles. How do I change to include the sections as well?

My (reduced) code:

```
\documentclass[12pt
    , structure=collection
    , pagelayout=compactaureo
    , version=draft
    , headerstyle=inner
    , footnotestyle=bulged
    , liststyle=indented
    , revauthortitle=false  % to have the author after the title 
    , titlefont=roman
    ]{suftesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \collectiontitle{ontobook}
    \collectioneditor {AUF}
    \tableofcontents
    \input{intro_papersSelected}
\end{document}
```

The article `intro_papersSelected` is:

```
\begin{article}
    \author { }
    \title{Introduction - The paper selected}
    \maketitle

\section{Papers to include:}
\begin{itemize}[align=left]
\item [{N}] The rationality of epistemology and the rationality of ontology.\\\\
Philosophers have proposed many different ontologies. 

\item [{K}] Ontology for spatio-temporal databases. \citet{frank03:9[TUW-119444]}
\end{itemize}

\section{test}
Towards a Mathematical Theory for Snapshot. In order to achieve
interoperability of \{GIS\}, the meaning of the 
data must be expressed in a compatible description. 

\end{article}
```

What must be changed to include the section names in the table of content? It currently lists only the article title `Introduction - The paper selected` and the page number.

If I add `\chapter{exampletitle} in the article included then the`exampletitle` is listed as 1 in the table of contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

before `\begin{document}`.

By the way, `hyperref` should be the last among the packages you load.

In the example I use `filecontents` in order to make it self-countained and to avoid clobbering my files.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-article}
\begin{article}
    \author { }
    \title{Introduction - The paper selected}
    \maketitle

\section{Papers to include:}
\begin{itemize}[align=left]
\item [{N}] The rationality of epistemology and the rationality of ontology.\\\\
Philosophers have proposed many different ontologies. 

\item [{K}] Ontology for spatio-temporal databases. \citet{frank03:9[TUW-119444]}
\end{itemize}

\section{test}
Towards a Mathematical Theory for Snapshot. In order to achieve
interoperability of \{GIS\}, the meaning of the 
data must be expressed in a compatible description. 

\end{article}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  12pt,
  structure=collection,
  pagelayout=compactaureo,
  version=draft,
  headerstyle=inner,
  footnotestyle=bulged,
  liststyle=indented,
  revauthortitle=false,  % to have the author after the title 
  titlefont=roman,
]{suftesi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\collectiontitle{ontobook}

\collectioneditor {AUF}

\tableofcontents

\input{\jobname-article}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the class documentation:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution and the hint to use `filecontent` and loading `hyperref` last. what is the best way to include the pdf output in a question?

Comment: @user855443 I usually do a screenshot and include the PNG file. The `filecontents` environment is very useful for examples here (not for the production version); using `\jobname` avoids the risk of clobbering existing files.